# How to recover from ransomware using Restore Points?

Tags: windows, ransomware

While reading about ways to recover from a ransomware on a Windows machine it's often recommended to use the **System Restore** functionality, e.g. to restore from a **Restore Point**.

I know that the Restore Points are located in the hidden System Volume Information folder on the root of the C: drive. If enabled, will it "survive" a ransomware? By default, only SYSTEM is permitted on that folder, but there are ways to grant permissions to basically any user using the built-in `cacls` command?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trusting a system on which malware ran even if you manage to restore it to an usable state.

Comment: @AndréBorie would you than trust the backup that was made shortly before the impact ?

Comment: Keep in mind that restore points are not full-system backups: they are backups of core system data, e.g. registry data. Most ransomware will leave core OS files alone, at least enough so you can run the system and cough up some bitcoins. Your user data is not part of a restore point and is very likely to be encrypted.

Comment: @Snowman but if I'm not mistaken you can configure System Protection to restore system setting and previous versions of files . . .

Comment: @adam86 previous versions of files such as device drivers, system libraries/executables, and other files you might find in the "windows" directory and subdirectories.

Comment: @Snowman I see, so basically there is no really much sense of doing a System Restore to a given Restore point as it won't get users data back. So, why it's recommended on almost every blog I've crossed till now ?

Comment: @adam86 that sounds like another question. Your current question as written starts with that as an assumption: "why do these blogs/articles recommend using restore points to deal with ransomware?" sounds like another question (if it is not already asked, of course). It would also be worth reading into the blogs to see if they can back up that assertion, although I imagine their justification is likely weak given the answers here. You might also want to reach out to their authors to ask that specifically if their existing writing does not answer it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some ransomware do compromise system restore points, others don't. To do it, they would need to have admin priveliges. But it is not at all unimaginable that malware would have that.

So should you rely on system restore points stored on your hard drive as protections against malware before the infection? Absolutely not! You need to have an external backup.

But could you rely on them to restore lost data after an infection, if you have no other backups? Yes, possibly, but only as a last resort. Be aware that your system may still be infected even after the restoration if the ransomware has infected the system image (or the ransomware could simply have encrypted them as well). You might also want to try to identify the ransomware, and do some research to figure out if that particular strand of malware compromise system restore points or not.

Also, as [Tsar](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/89155/tsar) points out, system restore points don't contain user data  most of the time. So you might not get much back from them.

Comment: System restore points most of the time doesn't contain user data, tho.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe, maybe not. It depends on the ransomware. There is no such thing as *the* ransomware. Each one of these annoying pests uses different methods to make a system unusable and they get constantly improved. Whatever a specific ransomware does, it *might* still allow a system restore or it *might* also destroy or disable this functionality.

The only effective precaution against ransomware are complete system backups on a physically separated systems.